# Changing Intel HD graphic card dedicated memory

Tags: graphics-card, windows-registry

I was searching on anything that can make my graphic card "Intel HD" work better!

I just found a way to increase the dedicated memory by adding a QWORD 64x file to registry and giving it "512" value

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\GMM

As you can see in the pic below, my old dedicated memory was 128, and now over 512!

**Is this thing work or it's just changing the number in "properties"?**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to increase your integrated VRAM via the BIOS. The method and ability will vary computer to computer. Look for something along the lines of "iGPU Memory". You may find yourself limited to something like 1GB or 512MB anyways though.

[image]

Be aware though that this is memory shared by the system, and unless you're hitting VRAM limits, you're not really going to be increasing performance, and may even be hurting it. If this is something you should do will depend on your workload.

Comment: I have checked my BIOS, there is no option for that at all

Comment: @NarzanQ. Probably nothing you can do then :/

Comment: Thanks for your time :) well I was asking if the method that I have used works or fake..

Comment: @NarzanQ. I'd recommend checking using [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)

Comment: I just checked my memory by CPU-Z > 1024

Comment: @NarzanQ. GPU-Z or CPU-Z? Different apps.

Comment: I just tried GPU-Z the usage memory while making benchmark around 1024mb, It seems the card use shared memory from the RAM, thanks for the idea, changing the registry doesn't change anything the same benchmark :)